# How to get crash reports from game Unity3d

Tags: unity

I am working on a project and I am in need of to gather CrashReports, email crash log, along with allowing the user to describe how the crash happened. I cannot find anything on how to do this, anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

-Learning Unity User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at [Cloud Diagnostics in Unity](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/11/06/performance-reporting-is-now-cloud-diagnostics/).

I used this feature to keep track of crashes in my game.

Comment: I like it, good job :)

Comment: This doesn't have to be a comment as it seems to be solving the issue. One tip I can give is when making answers with a link, try to explain in a few words what the link describes in detail, so even if the link gets broken in the future, users will be able to find a solution. In this situation you could explain in a few steps how to set up an example with Cloud Diagnostics. (I'm aware this has already been marked as correct, this is just a tip for future users)

Comment: Hi thanks for this will really explain in future. I thought giving a link for documentation will give a better way of understanding. Thanks Again